# Writing the where clause when looking up a folder?

Tags: php, mysqli

When using

```
$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = ?)";

// Bind parameter for statement
$optionstmt->bind_param("s", $selected_option);
```

This is fine, but if I want to use the WHERE clause to look for the variable within a folder, how is it suppose to be written? Is it like this below?

```
$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = 'VideoFiles/?')";

// Bind parameter for statement
$optionstmt->bind_param("s", $selected_option);
```

or like this:

```
$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = ?)";

// Bind parameter for statement
$optionstmt->bind_param("s", 'VideoFiles/$selected_option');
```

Does the single quote go around both the foldername and the variable name or does it just go around the folder name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the latter

```
$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = ?)";
```

There are a number of ways to quote the string, either of the following are fine:

```
$optionstmt->bind_param("s", 'VideoFiles/' . $selected_option);
// or
$optionstmt->bind_param("s", "VideoFiles/$selected_option");
```

Putting a variable in single quotes `'` however will not work.  The variable will not be translated to its actual value, you will get the literal string `$selected_option` in the query if you use single quotes.

Comment: Ok cool :) Thanks, I will mark your answer when it lets me in 9 mins

Comment: Alternately you could `OptionType = CONCAT('VideoFiles/', ?)`